# Find the Javascript code that is editing a div tag

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent

I have a div tag in HTML that looks something like this:

```
<div id='tiptip_content">...</div>
```

Now, I can see that by moving my mouse over certain places (mouseover event) on the webpage the text content of this tag is changing. The problem is, that I can't find the piece of Javascript code which is editing this tag. Does anyone have a way, either using some debugging tools or by writing some kind of script to find the code responsible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find event listeners on a DOM node?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node)

Comment: I think what you're looking for is something like this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox dev tools that come with the browser (not Firebug) lets you see events on an element. Clicking the little 'ev' bubble next to the element in the DOM view lets you see the code that handles the event.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check it in 2 ways.

1) Use browser Dev tools to find if the corresponding `<div>` has any events associated with it.

The problem with dev tools that it cant find if events are triggered via jquery. So

2) Look for a javascript peice of code like

$("#tiptip_content").mouseover();